# Tensorflow predict() is accurate on single sample but giving strange results when predicting on dataset

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, confusion-matrix

I'm experiencing strange results when predicting against a trained model.

If I use `model.predict()` with a dataset, I get spurious results.

If I iterate through the dataset one sample at a time, I get results in line with the accuracy of the trained model.

The model is built in Tensorflow to predict on the Stanford Dogs dataset, which I load like this:

```
dataset, info = tfds.load(name="stanford_dogs", with_info=True)
```

Although not best practice, I'm using the test dataset for validation:

```
training_data = dataset['train']
val_data = dataset['test']
```

I pre-process the dataset like this:

```
IMG_LEN = 224
IMG_SHAPE = (IMG_LEN,IMG_LEN,3)
N_BREEDS = 120

def preprocess(ds_row):
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(ds_row['image'], dtype=tf.float32)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, (IMG_LEN, IMG_LEN), method='nearest')
    
    label = tf.one_hot(ds_row['label'], N_BREEDS)  # TODO: Can remove one_hot and change loss function
    return image, label

def prepare(dataset, batch_size=None):
    ds = dataset.map(preprocess, num_parallel_calls=4)
    # ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)
    if batch_size:
        ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
        ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    return ds

train_batches = prepare(training_data, batch_size=32)
val_batches = prepare(val_data, batch_size=32)
```

My model is based on MobileNet V2:

```
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape = IMG_SHAPE,
                                               include_top=False,
                                               weights='imagenet')

base_model.trainable = False

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  base_model,
  tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(N_BREEDS, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adamax(0.0001),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy', 'top_k_categorical_accuracy'])
```

During training I get the following levels of accuracy

```
...
Epoch 25/30
375/375 [==============================] - 17s 45ms/step - loss: 0.9224 - accuracy: 0.7914 - top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.9777 - val_loss: 1.0945 - val_accuracy: 0.7309 - val_top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.9486
Epoch 26/30
375/375 [==============================] - 17s 45ms/step - loss: 0.8981 - accuracy: 0.7944 - top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.9784 - val_loss: 1.0755 - val_accuracy: 0.7331 - val_top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.9493
Epoch 27/30
375/375 [==============================] - 17s 44ms/step - loss: 0.8757 - accuracy: 0.7972 - top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.9788 - val_loss: 1.0581 - val_accuracy: 0.7359 - val_top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.9500
Epoch 28/30
375/375 [==============================] - 17s 44ms/step - loss: 0.8548 - accuracy: 0.8019 - top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.9796 - val_loss: 1.0417 - val_accuracy: 0.7378 - val_top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.9505
Epoch 29/30
375/375 [==============================] - 17s 45ms/step - loss: 0.8350 - accuracy: 0.8058 - top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.9807 - val_loss: 1.0271 - val_accuracy: 0.7389 - val_top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.9508
Epoch 30/30
375/375 [==============================] - 17s 44ms/step - loss: 0.8165 - accuracy: 0.8076 - top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.9813 - val_loss: 1.0134 - val_accuracy: 0.7404 - val_top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.9509
```

This is shown better here...

[image: Training Accuracy]

If I run `model.predict()` using:

```
test_images = dataset['test'].map(
    lambda x:  (tf.image.resize(x['image'], (IMG_LEN, IMG_LEN), method='nearest'))
).batch(1)

_test_labels = dataset['test'].map(
    lambda y: (y['label'])
)
test_labels = [l.numpy() for l in _test_labels]

tf_preds = model.predict(test_images)
```

I get the following output:

```
print(test_labels)
[67, 84, 57, 12, 88, 32, 55, 9, 68, 99, 10, 1, 60, 52, 96, 33, 108, 71, 11, 75, 77, 9, 50, 19, 41, 118, 30...]

print(tf_preds)
[12  65   0  65  56  65  91  65  12  50   0  65   0  65   0   0  65  65   58  65   0  65   0   0  65  65  65  65  65  50  65  65  65  97  65  65...]
```

Here's the confusion matrix for this:

[image]

I initially thought the model was not training, or was overfitting to the training data, but if I iterate over the data one sample at a time, I get this:

```
_preds = []
_actuals = []

for dog, label in zip(dataset['test'].take(n), test_labels[:n]):

    pic, _ = preprocess(dog)  # Convert to float32 and resize

    img_tensor = tf.expand_dims(pic,0)
    pred = model(img_tensor)

    top_components = tf.reshape(tf.math.top_k(pred, k=5).indices,shape=[-1])
    top_matches = [get_name(i) for i in top_components]
    actual = get_name(label)

    _preds.append(top_components[0])
    _actuals.append(label)

print(_preds)
[ 67  84  57   8  88  32  55   9  68  99  15   1  17  52  96  33 108  71...]
```

Which as you can see if very close to the ground truth labels:

```
print(test_labels)
[67, 84, 57, 12, 88, 32, 55, 9, 68, 99, 10, 1, 60, 52, 96, 33, 108, 71, 11, 75, 77, 9, 50, 19, 41, 118, 30...]
```

I know this is using `top_k()`, but the output is the same with `argmax()`

Here's the confusion matrix for this, which is aligned with what I would expect for a good model accuracy:

[image: Expected confusion matrix]

For completeness, here's `model.evaluate()` on the validation data which is inline with expected results:

```
model.evaluate(val_batches)
269/269 [==============================] - 175s 637ms/step - loss: 1.0301 - accuracy: 0.7336 - top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.9541
Out[93]:
[1.0301110744476318, 0.7335664629936218, 0.954079270362854]
```

My question is why would this be? This is the same model making predictions, it is not erroring because the data is malformed or has incorrect dimensions, it runs through the same pre-processing code for both scenarios, yet one is working as expected and one is wildly inaccurate, like the `model.predict()` is using an untrained model?